# UPDATE table by INNER JOIN and where clause

Tags: mysql

[image: Tables]

Got 2 tables as shown above. I want to update 'leaverecord.Consumed' from 'approved.Consumed' WHERE the leaverecord.name = approved.name and leaverecord.leavetype = approved.leavetype. Tried below query by getting **error of 'Invalid use of group function**

```
UPDATE leaverecord r INNER JOIN approved a
ON r.name = a.name
SET r.Consumed = SUM(DATEDIFF(a.todate,a.fromdate))
WHERE r.leavetype = a.leavetype AND
r.name = a.name
```

Comment: Screenshots don't help much, can you create some CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements? You'll get help faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the consumed in a subquery and `INNER JOIN` it with leaverecord and then do the `UPDATE` like below. No `WHERE` clause needed.

Try this:

```
update leaverecord r
inner join (
    select name, leavetype, sum(datediff(todate,fromdate)) consumed
    from approved
    group by name, leavetype
) a on r.name = a.name
and r.leavetype = a.leavetype
set r.consumed = a.consumed;
```

Comment: This has worked with a small correction in line 4 'a' after approved